# Objective-C Selector Help Needed

Tags: objective-c, selector

I keep on getting the error instance method perform selector not found... Can anyone help me with clearing this error?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "add.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SEL mySelector;

    id b = [[add alloc] init];

    mySelector = @selector(add2Num:);

    [b performSelector: mySelector]; // here is where i am getting the error

    [b release];

    return 0;
}
```

and then int the add.m file

```
#import "add.h"

@implementation add

-(void)add2Num
{
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 2;
    iResult = num1+ num2;
}

@end
```

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is likely that you typed `@selector(add2Num:)` instead of `@selector(add2Num)`.

Notice the ":" missing from the end of the selector name in my corrected syntax. Including the ":" indicates that the selector takes an argument, but your method `addNum` does not.

Comment: +1 moreover, when present the `:` is not only an indication for a parameter, but part of the method name.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a simple typo. I believe you meant `performSelector:`, not preformSelector:. Reverse the 'r' and the 'e'.

Comment: lol thanks. It is funny how long you can stare at something sometimes and the answer is so obvious.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, I'd be grateful if you accepted the answer.